# Bootstrapped manifest not allowed to use 'component' directive

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I trying prroviding command-line options by [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Providing_Command-Line_Options) example,
And I get this error in browser console:

- Bootstrapped manifest not allowed to use 'component' directive.
- Bootstrapped manifest not allowed to use 'contract' directive.
- Bootstrapped manifest not allowed to use 'category' directive.

params: `-no-remote -p Developer -jsconsole -ssprint:1137403`

here is contents of my files:

[install.rdf]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
    <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
          <em:id>@spidersprint</em:id>
          <em:type>2</em:type>
          <em:bootstrap>true</em:bootstrap>
          <em:unpack>false</em:unpack>
          <em:version>1.0.0</em:version>
          <em:name>SpiderSprint</em:name>
          <em:description>SpiderSprint extension (for self-using).</em:description>
          <em:creator>Alexander Macedonian</em:creator>
          <em:iconURL>resource://spidersprint/data/icon/s32.png</em:iconURL>
          <em:icon64URL>resource://spidersprint/data/icon/s64.png</em:icon64URL>

          <em:targetApplication>
            <Description>
              <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
              <em:minVersion>38.0a1</em:minVersion>
              <em:maxVersion>*</em:maxVersion>
            </Description>
          </em:targetApplication>
    </Description>
</RDF>
```

[chrome.manifest]:

```
component {75ceb908-0807-4395-affb-e0792ac4c548} components/commandlinehandler.js
contract @spidersprint/commandlinehandler;1 {75ceb908-0807-4395-affb-e0792ac4c548}
category command-line-handler CommandLineHandler @spidersprint/commandlinehandler;1
```

[commandlinehandler.js]

```
let {CC,Cc,Ci,Cu,Cr,components} = require('chrome');

Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
const CHROME_URI = "resource://spidersprint/data/";

function openWindow(aChromeURISpec, aArgument) {
    Services.ww.openWindow(null, aChromeURISpec, "_blank",
        "chrome,menubar,toolbar,status,resizable,dialog=no", aArgument);
}

function CommandLineHandler() {};

CommandLineHandler.prototype = {
    classDescription: "myAppHandler",
    classID: components.ID("{75ceb908-0807-4395-affb-e0792ac4c548}"),
    contractID: "@spidersprint/commandlinehandler;1",
    _xpcom_categories: [{
        category: "command-line-handler",
        entry: "s-ssprint"
    }],

    QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([
        Ci.nsICommandLineHandler
    ]),

    handle : function clh_handle(cmdLine)
    {
        try {
            var uristr = cmdLine.handleFlagWithParam("viewapp", false);
            if (uristr) {
                var uri = cmdLine.resolveURI(uristr);
                openWindow(CHROME_URI, uri);
                cmdLine.preventDefault = true;
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            Cu.reportError("incorrect parameter passed to -viewapp on the command line.");
        }

        if (cmdLine.handleFlag("ssprint", false)) {
            openWindow(CHROME_URI, null);
            cmdLine.preventDefault = true;
        }
    },

    helpInfo : "  -ssprint               Open My Application\n" +
        "  -viewapp <uri>       View and edit the URI in My Application,\n" +
        "                       wrapping this description\n"
};

var NSGetFactory = XPCOMUtils.generateNSGetFactory([CommandLineHandler]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That example uses chrome manifest that's only valid for the (deprecated) xul overlay extension type. In bootstrapped extensions you need to provide bootstrap.js instead and then use [Cu.import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.import) to load additional modules.

See [How to convert an overlay extension to restartless](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/How_to_convert_an_overlay_extension_to_restartless) for a code migration guide.

Additionally you might want to skip another step forward to use [SDK extension APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK), which essentially are a special form of bootstrapped extensions that provide some more stable API.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then how can I edit my bootstrap file? Because "jpm xpi" make a bootstrap file automaticaly and compress it to xpi file

Comment: XUL overlays are not *yet* deprecated. What has been announced is that there is a plan to deprecate them in the future (time frame specified as about 1 year from now, IIRC).

Comment: @Macedonian, just create a bootstrap.js yourself, jpm will use it if it's already present (restartless addon) or create one if not present (sdk addons).